# INSERT SELECT using a UNION statement in the WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query that goes something like this :

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO `destination_table` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
SELECT `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`
FROM `source_table`
WHERE `source_table`.`id` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `some_table`
    UNION DISTICT SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `some_other_table`
);
```

This does not work -- the query hangs indefinitely. The size of the tables is definitely not the problem, all tables have a fairly small number of records ( < 100k records). The query is fine and quite fast if I run it without the `UNION` :

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO `destination_table` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
SELECT `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`
FROM `source_table`
WHERE `source_table`.`id` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `some_table` -- I tried with `some_other_table` too, same result
);
```

or

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO `destination_table` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
SELECT `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`
FROM `source_table`
```

both work and are nice and fast (well under a second). So I imagine that the `UNION DISTICT SELECT ...` is the culprit here, but I don't know why.

What's wrong with that query and why does it hang ?

Using mysql 5.7 is that makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query seems to have a few typos, but I would suggest using exists logic here:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO destination_table (id, field1, field2, field3)
SELECT id, field1, field2, field3
FROM source_table t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table s1 WHERE s1.id = t1.id) OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_other_table s2 WHERE s2.id = t1.id);
```

The possible advantage of using exists in this way is that MySQL can stop searching as soon as it finds the first matching `id` in either of the subqueries on the two tables.  You may find that adding an index on the `id` columns in the two other would help (assuming that `id` be not already indexed):

```
CREATE INDEX some_idx_1 ON some_table (id);
CREATE INDEX some_idx_2 ON some_other_table (id);
```

This should speed up the lookup of the `id` in the two dependent tables.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the typos in the first query, I changed the table / field names and I must've messed up. Changing to the `EXISTS` logic did not work, the query still hung but adding indexes did make the original query work just fine at a very reasonable speed (< 2 secs)

Answer (score 1):

You could work around the problem by rephrasing the query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `destination_table` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`)
SELECT `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`
FROM `source_table`
WHERE `source_table`.`id` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `some_table`
)
OR `source_table`.`id` IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `some_other_table`
);
```

Comment: Thank you ! And yes, this does work, I was trying to understand why the original query was hanging.